# Float content with width 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying align all content to left side, but doesn't work well.
This is my code:

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 250px; background-color: red;">
  asdfasdf
  <br>asdfasdf
  <br>asdfasdf
  <br>asdfasdf
  <br>asdfasdf
  <br>asdfasdf
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="top-content-right" style="border-left: 15px solid #37afd2; background-color: #444444; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 600; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; width:600px;">
    <span class="fa fa-briefcase space-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    <span class="text-title-right">Example</span>
    <p style="color: #000000;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

I what this (but with example bar, width:100%):

**Example1:**
[image]
**Example2:**
[image]

Is possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand. the code you provided gives the result in your objective :S is it that tiny blue line in the 'example' bar you're refering to?

Comment: Thank for your reply. In my example (code) the tiny blue line is below to the red retangle, i do not want that.

Comment: Just adjusted my example. Also, any reason you're using inline CSS instead of chucking them in a stylesheet?

Comment: Are you asking how to move that red rectangle *below* the black bar??? Your question is doing a *horrible* job at describing the *actual* problem.

Comment: One image say much more that 100 words.
http://i.imgur.com/IVbx5tj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

Move the `top-content-right` below the left floated div, remove its `width: 100%` and add `margin-left: 250px` and it will work as expected

When you float an element to the left and want another appear at its right, the right element need to be after in the markup and have a left margin matching the floated's width.

And if you would like to float an element to the right and want another appear at its left, the left element need to be after in the markup and have a right margin matching the floated's width.

```css
.top-content-right ~ .top-content-right {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 250px; background-color: red; margin: 0 5px 5px 0;">
  asdfasdf<br>
  asdfasdf<br>
  asdfasdf<br>
  asdfasdf<br>
  asdfasdf<br>
  asdfasdf<br>
</div>
<div class="top-content-right" style="border-left: 15px solid #37afd2; background-color: #444444; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 600; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; margin-left: 250px;">
  <span class="text-title-right">Example</span> 
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa fa-briefcase space-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
  <p style="color: #000000;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="top-content-right" style="border-left: 15px solid #37afd2; background-color: #444444; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 600; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; margin-left: 250px;">
  <span class="text-title-right">Example</span> 
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fa fa-briefcase space-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
  <p style="color: #000000;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have margin-left: 250px; in first bar.. you can't do it with same style for all bars? This code will be created dynamically. 
Beside the red rectangle can have two bars (margin-left: 250px)..Do u understand? The code doesnt work for all scenarios.

Comment: @Jerson When you ask a question you need to post the possible scenarios or else no answer will ever cover that, second, we can't cover all aspects of a question but we can show how to overcome an issue, after that it is up to you to use that new how-to and implement it on your own code. I've solved your initial question so the most appropriate would be to accept it and then post a new question with the extended scenario or else all the given answers here will be invalid.

Comment: @Jerson Thank you. If you post a link to the new question here I will have a look ... I don't think it can be solved with float though (unless you add a script) but it might with `flex`

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this.. I've put them into two container Divs called left and right. I've set them to percentage widths - change these to decide how much of thw width you want them to take up. Your issue was that A. the example bar had no float B. you were working with a defined width but the example bar had a 5px border.

```
<div class="left" style="float: left; width: 40%;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 100%; background-color: red; margin: 0 5px 5px 0;">
            asdfasdf<br>
            asdfasdf<br>
            asdfasdf<br>
            asdfasdf<br>
            asdfasdf<br>
            asdfasdf<br>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right" style="width:60%; float: right;">
<div class="top-content-right" style="border-left: 15px solid #37afd2; background-color: #444444; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 600; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; width:100%;">
<span class="text-title-right">Example</span> 
</div></div>
        <div>


                <span class="fa fa-briefcase space-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 

                <p style="color: #000000;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>

            </div>
```

here's the JS fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/kow1jxo3/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. See my image, and you will see that the example bar is next to the red rectangle

Comment: Wait :S So you want more content below it? if you could clarify wht you want the content below it to look like, I'd be happy to add the necessary code

Comment: Did you want the example titles below it to be full width? if so, you just need to adjust the width of the div for each occurrence - because you're using inline CSS the CSS rules are copying down with the code.

Comment: I only want repeat the code, like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/IVbx5tj.png

Comment: Not a problem, just adjust the width of the bottom two divs to 100%. see updated fiddle

Comment: Change width: 60% to width 100% of the bottom two divs.